# Getting current user balance of an aToken for a specific asset in AAVE v2 protocol

Tags: tokens, contract-invocation, dapps, balances, aave

As [AAVE protocol V2 documentation](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/the-core-protocol/atokens) says:

> aTokens are interest-bearing tokens that are minted and burned upon deposit and withdraw. The aTokens' value is pegged to the value of the corresponding deposited asset at a 1:1 ratio, and can be safely stored, transferred or traded. All interest collected by the aTokens reserves are distributed to aTokens holders directly by continuously increasing their wallet balance.

After depositing some amount of an ERC-20 token such as DAI, I need to know the current aToken balance of a user for the same asset (DAI in this case), so that I would be able to calculate user investment's profit.
It is also mentioned in the [documents](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/the-core-protocol/protocol-data-provider#getuserreservedata) that there is an `IProtocolDataProvider` interface with a `getUserReserveData` method which gives asset address as well as the user address as arguments and returns `currentATokenBalance` as part of the return value. However, I could not find the aforementioned smart contract file in [AAVE protocol V2's GitHub](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2). Did it change silently overnight and documents are not getting the new updates yet? Am I doing the right thing for getting a user's current `aToken` balance? If not, what is the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of research, I found out that they slightly renamed it to `AaveProtocolDataProvider` and moved it into new path: `@aave/protocol-v2/contracts/misc/AaveProtocolDataProvider.sol`
Besides that, the balance of any `aToken` can be acquired directly by calling its `balanceOf` method.